# What does this phrase outside Yue Fei Temple mean? (Characters identified: 乾坤正氣)

Tags: classical-chinese

[image]

Another phrase as [岳王廟](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yue_Fei_Temple) that I can't make out, this one outside the main courtyard. I can only make out the last two characters: 正氣. I found this image at [kknews](http://www.zjxzj.com/html/2017/tbtj_0704/7383.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characters are

> ⿰龺乙⿰土正氣

In modern characters, this would be written as

> 乾坤正氣

---

The tricky characters are the first and second, where

- The right side of the first character is 「乙」
- The right side of the second character is [an old way of writing 「申」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=271)

Comment: So, what does 乾坤正氣 means?

Comment: 乾坤= the universe;正氣= aura of justice   ; 乾坤正氣 means “there are justice in the universe